# how to get newline from server through ajax as javascript and execute it in client?

Tags: javascript, ajax

i am getting reply from server as xyz.innerHTML='blah blah';
in blah blah i want to send newline and it should be displayed as new line in html.
what i have to do? please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i am getting reply from server as
>   xyz.innerHTML='blah blah'; in blah
>   blah i want to send newline and it
>   should be displayed as new line in
>   html. what i have to do? please help.

Add `<br />` to it:

```
xyz.innerHTML='blah blah<br />';
```

Note: You can add the `<br />` from server-side script too.